# Windows 8, MediaCapture.StopPreviewAsync from javascript

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

I'm using the Window's [MediaCapture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.aspx) class from a Win8 html/javascript application. When I stop displaying the preview video in a `<video />` tag, I figured I'd need to use the `StopPreviewAsync` method to end the preview stream. However, the [MediaCapture.StopPreviewAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.stoppreviewasync.aspx) method doesn't appear to be available from javascript. It's not documented on MSDN for javascript and attempting to call it results in a runtime error:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'stopPreviewAsync'.
```

Is it not necessary to close the stream when using a `MediaCapture` instance from javascript? Why does it exist for only C#/C++/VB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting an answer from the Microsoft team that develops the Media Capture API. There is no *guaranteed* method of closing the stream and giving up the camera. The only option is to remove all references to the stream and then call `CollectGarbage()`. The camera will be released whenever the associated memory is reclaimed. Apparently a more explicit method of releasing the camera will be coming at some point for Windows 8.1.